# Two step click process fails one step

Tags: javascript, html, css

The following code is supossed to do the following two click process:

1. First click on .imagenes makes opacity to drop down,  and .logo visible.
2. Second click on .imagenes returns its opacity to 1 and .logo hides again.

Instead, it goes through the two click cycle but .logo does not show up.
Can you figure out why?

`

```js
const imagenes = document.querySelectorAll('.imagenes');
const logos = document.querySelectorAll('.logo');

imagenes.forEach((imagen, index) => {
  let count = 0;
  imagen.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (count % 2 == 0) {
      imagen.style.opacity = 0.1;
      logos[index].style.opacity = 1;
    } else {
      imagen.style.opacity = 1;
      logos[index].style.opacity = 0;
    }
    count++;
  });
});
```

```css
   

 html {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
    
    body {
      max-width: 1500px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .gridA {
      display: grid;
      width: 50%;
      height: auto;
      grid-gap: .5rem;
      grid-auto-rows: minmax(auto, min-content);
      grid-template-columns: 1fr;
      margin-right: .25rem;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .gridB {
      display: grid;
      width: 50%;
      height: auto;
      grid-gap: .5rem;
      grid-auto-rows: minmax(auto, min-content);
      grid-template-columns: 1fr;
      margin-left: .25rem;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto; /*img use its full width leaving empty height space*/
        object-fit: cover;
        display: block; /*fill empty space remaining after adding img*/
        max-height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    #A, #B {
      position: relative;
    }

    .logo {
      position: absolute;
      visibility: hidden;
      top:0;
    }

    .youtube-link {
        position: absolute;
        top: 80%;
        left: 39%;
        width: 15%;
        
    }
    
    .video-link {
        position: absolute;
        top:100%;
        width: 10%;
        left: 44%;
    }
    
    .youtube-link2 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 75%;
        left: 42%;
        width: 15%;
    } 
    
    .youtube-link2:hover {
        opacity: .6;
    }
    
    .video-link:hover {
        opacity: .6;
    } 
    
    .youtube-link:hover {
        opacity: .6;
    }
```

```html
<<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="gridA">

<div id ="A" class="box">
  
  <div class="imagenes">
    <img src="spotify-still.jpg">
  </div>
  
  <div class="logo">
    <img id="Alog" src="Spotify Logo (PNG720p) - Vector69Com.png">
      <a>
        <a class="youtube-link2" target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ob_q2HsHWM">
          <img id="youspot" src="pngwing.com(1) copy.png" class="youtube-btn">
        </a>
      </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div ID ="B" class="box">
  
  <div class="imagenes">
    <img src="audi-q3-1-by-marc-trautmann 2.jpg">
  </div>
  
  <div class="logo">
    <img id="Blog" src="Audi_logo_PNG3.png">
  </div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="gridB">
</div>

<script src="JS.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I didn't understand your question fully. However, you have issues with your HTML closing tags. Also, with CSS, we do not have `hide` as a value for the property `opacity`. If you want to make it transparent, use `opacity: 0` or for full opaque use, `opacity: 1`. Opacity value ranges from `0 - 1`. Can you please update your question in a more understandable way with the mentioned corrections so that anyone from the community could help you?

Answer (score 0):

You're only Changing the opacity one way, but you'll need to change it back on second click.

Lets simplefy this by adding 2 CSS classes: `hide` and `show`, which have `opacity` `0` or `1`.

Then you can loop over all the `box`'es :

```js
[ ...document.querySelectorAll('.box') ].forEach(box => {
```

And get the images and logo inside that box:

```
let boxImagenes = box.querySelector('.imagenes');
let boxLogo = box.querySelector('.logo');
```

Here we can add an `EventListener` that will [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) the `show` class with `hide`, and visa versa for the images.

```
boxImagenes.addEventListener("click", () => {
        boxLogo.classList.replace('hide', 'show');
        boxImagenes.classList.replace('show', 'hide');
    });
```

Then add another `EventListener` for the Logo that will revert the action from the first click

---

**Note**: Removed the link + added placeholder images for a better demo

```js
[ ...document.querySelectorAll('.box') ].forEach(box => {

    let boxImagenes = box.querySelector('.imagenes');
    let boxLogo = box.querySelector('.logo');
    
    boxImagenes.addEventListener("click", () => {
        boxLogo.classList.replace('hide', 'show');
        boxImagenes.classList.replace('show', 'hide');
    });    
    
    boxLogo.addEventListener("click", () => {
        boxLogo.classList.replace('show', 'hide');
        boxImagenes.classList.replace('hide', 'show');
    });    
});
```

```css
#A {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.logo {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
}

.show { opacity: 1; }
.hide { opacity: 0; }
```

```html
<div id ="A" class="box">
    <div class="imagenes show">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/50?random=1">
    </div>
    <div class="logo hide">
        <img id="Alog" src="https://picsum.photos/50?random=2">
        <img id="youspot" src="https://picsum.photos/50?random=3" class="youtube-btn">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You code is very easy to understand and I have made some adjustments I am testing at the moment. However I am not making it work for some reasons I am trying to figure out now.

Comment: You could add a second snippet in your original question with your new code if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike `imagenes`, there on `logo` you are using *pictures* that have spaces in them.

You can either remove those spaces or you can use the *characters* that replace space which are normally a plus (`+`) sign or `%20`.